# How do i run a command only when a file is open

Tags: python, if-statement, operating-system

I'm trying to make a file change its name as long as another file is running,
and when i exit the running file i want the changed file name back to its original name

the code i used only seems to open the file and ignore the commands under it,
would really appreciate the help.

```
import os
import time


if os.startfile(r'C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\test\file.exe'):
    time.sleep(3)
    os.rename(r'C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\test\name.txt',r'C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\test\name2.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work, but it probably isn't the best idea:

EDIT: added prints and time.sleep to check every 10 seconds

```
import os
import psutil
import time


process_name = 'some_process'
file_name = 'some_file_path'
replacement = 'some_replacement_file_name'

while True:
    print(f'looking for {process_name}')
    time.sleep(10)
    if process_name in (p.name() for p in psutil.process_iter()):
        print(f'{process_name} started')
        os.rename(file_name, replacement)
        while True:
            time.sleep(10)
            if not process_name in (p.name() for p in psutil.process_iter()):
                print(f'{process_name} stopped')
                os.rename(replacement, file_name)
                break
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to rename once and then run your `while` loop to check the process list?  As it is, your top `while` loop never ends.

Comment: It is infinite on purpose... as long as the script is running so you can spawn and kill the process and it will continue to rename each time but still, not the best idea, maybe some time.sleep(10) at the front of the while loops to make it not run so much

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Windows computer handy so I can't test this.  However, the Python documentation for `os.startfile` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) doesn't specify anything regarding the return value.  This makes me suspect that the return value is `None` or something like that.  If so, that would explain why your code block isn't being run.

This line from that documentation should be helpful:

> startfile() returns as soon as the associated application is launched. There is no option to wait for the application to close, and no way to retrieve the application’s exit status.

Therefore, since you're trying to do something (i.e., revert the file name) once the process terminates, you want to use a different function than `os.startfile`.  I'm not that familiar with Windows so perhaps someone else can point you in the right direction.